# How to use firebase authentication in Node.js application?

Tags: node.js, express, firebase-authentication

I tried to implement the firebase authentication in my Node + Express application. But can not figure out how to authenticate an user using email and password. It would be helpful if there is a tutorial or example project.

Answer (score 3):

I know this might help someone in need of help like Shams Nahid, there is firebase authentication tutorial that i would recommend for this. [Firebase Authentication Tutorial using](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLJm7_t7JnSjn__VC3sK86o2YlUuwlPKkO)

To implement user login using firebase, Node js and express, follow these simple steps

Step 1. Follow this documentation about firebase authentication [How to use email and password to sign in](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth.html?authuser=0#createuserwithemailandpassword)

Step 2. Create a **login.ejs** file

```
<!doctype html>
 <html>
 <head> <title>Login into your account</title>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.1.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <!-- Add Firebase products that you want to use -->
    <script  src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.1.0/firebase-auth.js"</script>
    <script  src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.1.0/firebase-firestore.js" 
    </script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.1.0/firebase-database.js"> 
    </script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" 
    href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font- 
    awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <style>body{padding-top:80px;}</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container " >
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 ">
        <h1><span class="fa fa-sign-in"></span> Login</h1>
                <!-- LOGIN FORM -->
        <fieldset>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Email</label>
                <input type="email" id="txtemail" value="" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Password</label>
                <input type="password" id="txtpassword" value="" class="form- 
           control">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" id="loginButton" onclick="signInUsers()"class="btn 
            btn-warning"><a href="/login">Login</a>
            </button>
            <button type="submit" id="logoutButton" onclick="logout()"class="btn btn- 
            warning">logout</button>
        </fieldset>
        <hr>
     </div>
    </div>
    <script src="/js/firebase.js"></script>
   </body>
  </html>
```

Step 3. create an authentication script

**firebase.js**

```
    // Your web app's Firebase configuration
var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "INSERT HERE YOUR API FROM FIREBASE CONSOLE",
    authDomain: "INSERT YOUR DOMAIN",
    databaseURL: "INSERT YOUR DATABASE URL",
    projectId: "INSERT HERE YOUR PROJECT ID",
    storageBucket: "canon-4f6d8.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "INSERT HERE YOUR MESSAGING ID FROM FIREBASE",
    appId: "1YOUR APP ID FROM FIREBASE"
};
// Initialize Firebase
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  function signInUsers(){
      var email = document.getElementById('txtemail').value;
      var pass = document.getElementById('txtpassword').value;
      firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass)
         .catch(function(error) {
              // Handle Errors here.
             let errorCode = error.code;
             let errorMessage = error.MESSAGE;
             console.log(errorCode);
             console.log(errorMessage);
          });
  }
  //check if user is logged in or not
function checkIfLogedIn(){
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
        if (user) { // if the user is logged in
            console.log(user)
            var emailv =user.email;
            console.log("User is signed in. with email: "+ emailv);
            document.getElementById('loginButton').setAttribute('style','display: none;visibility: hidden;');
            document.getElementById('logoutButton').setAttribute('style','display: inline-block;visibility: visible;')
        } else { // if the user is not logged in
            console.log("No user is signed in.");
            document.getElementById('loginButton').setAttribute('style','display: none;visibility: visible;');
            document.getElementById('logoutButton').setAttribute('style','display: inline-block;visibility: hidden;')
        }
    });
}

window.onload=function(){
    checkIfLogedIn()
}
function logout(){
    firebase.auth().signOut();
    checkIfLogedIn()
}
```

Step 3. Create your app.js script that you will be running

**app.js** file

```
   var express=require('express')
var logger=require('morgan')
var passport = require('passport');
var bodyParser=require('body-parser')
var admin=require('firebase-admin')
var path = require('path');
var serviceAccount=require('./canon-serviceKey.json')
var firebaseAdmin=admin.initializeApp({
   credential:admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
   databaseURL: "INSERT YOUR FIREBASE DB URL"
})
///database reference
var database=firebaseAdmin.database()

//create instance of express app
var app=express()
//we want to serve js and html in ejs
//ejs stands for embedded javascript
app.set('view engine','ejs')
//we also want to send css images and other static files in views folder
//app.use(express.static('views'))
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/views/')));
app.set('views',__dirname+'/views/')
//Give the server access to user input
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended:false}))
app.use(logger('dev'))

//create authentication middle ware
function checkLoggedIn(request, resposense, next) {// if user is authenticated in the session, carry on
    if (request.isAuthenticated())
        return next();// if they aren't redirect them to the index page
    resposense.redirect('/');
}

app.get('/',function(request,response){
    response.render('login.ejs')
})
app.get('/login', function(request,response){
    response.render('profile.ejs')
});
app.get('/logout', function(request,response){
    response.render('login.ejs')
});

   app.listen(port,function(){
   console.log('App running on port'+port)
})
```

**NOTE:** Make sure you install the necessary packages first using npm install package-name
such as

1. express
2. morgan
3. firebase-admin
4. body-parser

After doing the above steps you run your app.js using **node app.js** and you will be good to go.
i hope this helps some one with the same issue about firebase authentication using node js and express

Comment: @shams-nahid, I hope that answer gave you insights on how to tackle your problem